# Purge command discord.js

Tags: discord.js

I am trying to create a purge command and it works, but I want the bot to not delete the pinned messages when I use the command. What do I include in the code to prevent it from delting the pinned messages? Currently this is the code -

```
if(message.content.toLowerCase().startsWith("s!purge")) {
let arg = message.content.split(" ")
  message.delete() 
let clear = arg[1];
if(!clear) return message.channel.send(`:x: | \`Incorrect usage of command you need to provide an amount of messages to Clear.\` 
**Example:** \`s!purge 50\` `)
if(isNaN(clear)) return message.channel.send(":x: | ``Please Put a Valid Number to Clear messages.``")
if(clear > 100) return message.channel.send(":x: | ``I can't Clear more than 100 messages.``")
if(clear < 1) return message.channel.send(":x: | ``You cannot Clear less than 1 message.``")
message.channel.bulkDelete(clear)
message.channel.send(`:white_check_mark: | \`Succesfully cleared ${clear} messages! \` `)
.then(message => 
 setTimeout(()=> message.delete(), 2000)
 )
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a method to check if a message is pinned or not. Which is [message.pinned](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/Message?scrollTo=pinned).

And do

```js
if (!message.pinned) {
    // delete the message
}
```

I hope that solves your issue!

or else you can do `const nonPinnedMsgs = await message.channel.messages.fetch({ limit: thePurgeAmount }).filter(m => m.pinned)` and bulk delete (nonPinnedMsgs)

Comment: Thanks! I replace thePurgeAmount with ```arg[1]``` and it worked!
I used this code :-

```await message.channel.bulkDelete((await message.channel.messages.fetch({limit: arg[1]})).filter(m => !m.pinned)```